# setup.py install leaving files where they are

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I'm working with a custom package that I'd like to modify while I'm using it.  When I run `python setup.py install --user`, it copies the files to another directory --- so everytime I make a change, I have to re-`install` with `-f`.  Is there a way to install without making a copy of the `.py` files --- so that I can keep modifying them in place?

Comment: Why do you reinstall if you can change the files in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an "editable install":

```
pip install --user -e .
```

This will add the current directory to your python path instead of copying the files into the packages directory.

Comment: Thanks!  Note: it needs to be `pip install --user -e .`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the order but it seems unreasonable to me why the order of options is relevant. Must be a bug...

Comment: It looks like `-e` doesn't mean the current directory --- it means whatever directory you point to; in this case `.`